# How to test equality between class objects using FEST assertThat(...) method?

Tags: java, junit4, fest, assertj

How to test if class objects are equal using FEST `assertThat(...)` method?

Example:

```
import static org.fest.assertions.api.Assertions.assertThat; 

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    assertThat(findClass()).isEqualTo(Integer.class);
}

private Class<?> findClass() {
    // logic for finding a class object
    return String.class;
}
```

The above does not compile. The `isEqualTo` method complains. Is there some other method I should use to test equality between class objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should use [AssertJ](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core); FEST is outdated by this package. But since AssertJ shares a similar syntax, the transition will be easy.

Second, well, with AssertJ, this works out of the box... This compiles for me:

```
// irrelevant code, then
    assertThat(findClass()).isEqualTo(Integer.class);
}

private Class<?> findClass()
{
    return Integer.class;
}
```

So, maybe you have another problem?

Comment: No problem ;) Note that since `Class<?>` "instances" are singletons, you can use `.isSameAs()`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using assertJ, the proper way to do this is with `isInstanceOf()` method. Always use the more specific assertJ matchers when possible. They're more semantic, and give better error results.

http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/Assert.html#isInstanceOf(java.lang.Class)

```
    assertThat(object).isInstanceOf(Foo.class);
```